# Fundamental Theorem related computation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to solve for specifics about A, an m x n matrix. I have been given a 3x1 matrix, M, and a 5x3 matrix, N, along with the fact that Col(A)=Col(M) and Col(N) is a subset of Null(A). I am trying to solve for multiple specifics about A, such as the values of m and n, Null dimension, etc.

I have attempted rearranging the Fundamental Theorem to yield certain things, however I seem to be stuck when I reach a point. Is there a way to go about this question using the fundamental theorem that I am missing?

Comment: What are you stuck on? Are you talking about the Rank-nullity theorem? Does Col(A) mean the column space of A?

Comment: Yes, that is what Col(A) is referring to. I believe I am supposed to use the theorem stating R^n=Row(A) + Null(A) and R^m = Col(A) + Null(A^T)